# Stagnant Water smell during/after a washing machine cycle

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

Currently have awashing machine in the utility, every time the wife does a wash it tends to stink like stagnant water in there, I am making an assumption here that the waste feed from the washing machine is pushing the water out and the issue is that the water is sitting in the trap and the smell is obviously emanating from the plug hole.

I've come to this assumption because if I run the hot tap into the sink for a while it clears the smell (as I guess it pushes the last of the stagnant water around the trap). Am I right in thinking here the best course of action is I need to move the waste feed connection to the opposite side of the trap? Picture below.

[image]

The waste pipe is the grey pipe with a jubilee clip.